# Flask app deployment on Google App Engine Flex using Docker

Tags: python, docker, google-app-engine, flask, gunicorn

I want to deploy a Flask app on Google App Engine Flex using Docker.

I set up the Docker image locally and managed to run a Flask app using the commands 
`docker build -t myreponame .` and then `docker run -p 4000:80 myreponame`.
I was then able to see my app on the URL http://localhost:4000 and it worked fine.

However when I try and deploy it on Google App Engine using `gcloud app deploy`, and go to the URL http://YOUR_PROJECT_ID.appspot.com, I get a "502 Server Error".

I am suspecting maybe a port configuration.
Should I define the following differently in my Flask code?

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
    HOST = '0.0.0.0'
    PORT = 80
    app.run(HOST, PORT, debug=True)
```

Or should I define my `app.yaml` file differently?

```
runtime: custom
env: flex
entrypoint: gunicorn -b :$PORT app:app
```

My `Dockerfile` contains the following:

```
FROM python:2.7
WORKDIR /app
COPY . /app
RUN pip install --trusted-host pypi.python.org -r requirements.txt
EXPOSE 80
CMD ["python", "app.py"]
```

Any help would be very welcome. Many thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The issue was indeed in the port configuration.
The App Engine front end routes incoming requests on port 8080 (reference: https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/flexible/custom-runtimes/build?authuser=0), so I changed my Flask code to:

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
    HOST = '0.0.0.0'
    PORT = 8080
    app.run(HOST, PORT, debug=True)
```

I removed the entrypoint config from app.yaml:

```
runtime: custom
env: flex
```

and changed Dockerfile to:

```
FROM python:2.7
WORKDIR /app
COPY . /app
RUN pip install --trusted-host pypi.python.org -r requirements.txt
EXPOSE 8080
CMD ["gunicorn", "app:app", "-b", ":8080", "--timeout", "300"]
```

Answer (score -1):

Why don't you use docker run with '-p 80:80' instead of '-p 4000:80'?

Or you also have a Nginx or sth to making port forwarding?

Comment: I was actually following the instructions in the Docker tutorial https://docs.docker.com/get-started/part2/#build-the-app
I don't use Nginx or any tool to making port forwarding.

Comment: I actually thought `gcloud app deploy` would take care of the port forwarding for me. Is there any option I should add to that command?